# How to clear previous api result when a new query is made

Tags: javascript, dom

So I'm using https://calendarific.com api and am trying to make an "app" where you can click on your country and it returns the holidays based on the current month. It kinda works except when I click on one country and then another the previous countries result stays on the top and the new country's holidays get put to the bottom of the page.

How can I remove previous results when a new one is made?

Javascript (sorry if it's a bit messy):

```
  countrySelect.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Api url
        let url = `https://calendarific.com/api/v2/holidays?&api_key=a7167178ffb6d2d7d8d9c1e05d98eab926f595e9&country=${buttonValue}&year=2020`;

        fetch(url)
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => {

        // Filters holiday's to the current month
            var currentMonthHolidays = data.response.holidays.filter(holiday => {

              var holidayDate = new Date(holiday.date.iso);
              var holidayMonth = holidayDate.getMonth();
              var date = new Date();
              var currentMonth = date.getMonth();
              return currentMonth === holidayMonth;

            })


            // Build holiday table
            function buildTable(data){
              let table = document.getElementById('resultTable');


              let col = [];
              // Get the index of the api titles
                for (let i = 0; i < currentMonthHolidays.length; i++) {
                    for (let key in currentMonthHolidays[i]) {
                        if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                            col.push(key);
                        }
                    }
                    console.log(col)
                }

                //Create table header row using the extracted headers above.
                let tr = table.insertRow(-1);                   // table row.

                for (let i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
                    let th = document.createElement("th");      // table header.
                    th.innerHTML = col[i];
                    tr.appendChild(th);
                }


              // add json data to the table as rows.
              for (let i = 0; i < currentMonthHolidays.length; i++) {

                  tr = table.insertRow(-1);

                  for (let j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
                      let tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
                      tabCell.innerHTML = currentMonthHolidays[i][col[j]];
                  }
              }

            }

            buildTable(currentMonthHolidays);


                console.log(currentMonthHolidays);

                //handles error
              }, networkError => {
                alert(networkError)
              })

          })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only concerned about just getting new data on top,
in your code just add :
`table.removeChild(table.tBodies[0]);`

which becomes :-

```
countrySelect.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Api url
        let url = `https://calendarific.com/api/v2/holidays?&api_key=a7167178ffb6d2d7d8d9c1e05d98eab926f595e9&country=${buttonValue}&year=2020`;

        fetch(url)
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => {

        // Filters holiday's to the current month
            var currentMonthHolidays = data.response.holidays.filter(holiday => {

              var holidayDate = new Date(holiday.date.iso);
              var holidayMonth = holidayDate.getMonth();
              var date = new Date();
              var currentMonth = date.getMonth();
              return currentMonth === holidayMonth;

            })


            // Build holiday table
            function buildTable(data){
              let table = document.getElementById('resultTable');


              let col = [];
              // Get the index of the api titles
                for (let i = 0; i < currentMonthHolidays.length; i++) {
                    for (let key in currentMonthHolidays[i]) {
                        if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                            col.push(key);
                        }
                    }
                    console.log(col)
                }

                //Create table header row using the extracted headers above.
                let tr = table.insertRow(-1);                   // table row.

                for (let i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
                    let th = document.createElement("th");      // table header.
                    th.innerHTML = col[i];
                    tr.appendChild(th);
                }
              /*
              since all <tr> are wrapped inside <tbody>, so just remove the old one and you are good to go 
              */
              table.removeChild(table.tBodies[0]); 
              // add json data to the table as rows.
              for (let i = 0; i < currentMonthHolidays.length; i++) {

                  tr = table.insertRow(-1);

                  for (let j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
                      let tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
                      tabCell.innerHTML = currentMonthHolidays[i][col[j]];
                  }
              }

            }

            buildTable(currentMonthHolidays);


                console.log(currentMonthHolidays);

                //handles error
              }, networkError => {
                alert(networkError)
              })

          })
```